# Python Recursion - Swap words in a sentence via dictionary index, get all permutations

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function which takes a sentence, iterates through each word, compares the words to a dictionary, and replaces the word if they match within the dictionary. In the end, it should return every permutation possible.

For the sentence example: "For now it is never to late" should return the following: 
{"For now it is never to late", "4 now it is never to late", "4 now it is never 2 late", "4 now it is never 2 l8", "4 now it is never to l8", "for now it is never 2 late", "for now it is never 2 l8", "for now it is never to l8"}

I currently have the following snippet of code, which works for the first loop through and returns ['4 now it is never to late', '4 now it is never 2 late', '4 now it is never 2 l8'], but I cannot seem to figure out a method for getting the remaining permutations.

```
wordChangeDict = {'for':'4',
                    'to': '2',
                    'late': 'l8'}

def phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index):
    if index > len(phrase)-1:
        return resultStrings
    else:
        word = phrase[index]
        if word in wordChangeDict:
            phrase[index] = wordChangeDict[word]
            resultStrings.append(' '.join(phrase))
        return phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index+1)


testPhrase = "for now it is never to late"
phraseArray = testPhrase.split()
for idx, word in enumerate(phraseArray):
    modifiedPhrases = []
    modifiedPhrases = phrase2Slang(phraseArray, modifiedPhrases, idx)
    print modifiedPhrases
```

**Update (Answer)**
Below, Arief pointed out that my initial list was mutable, causing the blank results. After fixing this, I was able to use one of my original solutions of a multiple recursion loop (dropping the for loop which led into the recursive calls as well):

```
import copy
wordChangeDict = {'for':'4',
                  'to': '2',
                  'late': 'l8'}

def phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index):
    phrase = copy.deepcopy(phrase)
    if index == -1:
        return resultStrings
    else:
        word = phrase[index]
        if word in wordChangeDict:
            phrase2 = copy.deepcopy(phrase)
            phrase2[index] = wordChangeDict[word]
            resultStrings.append(' '.join(phrase2))
            phrase2Slang(phrase2, resultStrings, index-1)
        return phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index-1)


testPhrase = "for now it is never to late"
phraseArray = testPhrase.split()
modifiedPhrases = []
modifiedPhrases = phrase2Slang(phraseArray, modifiedPhrases, len(phraseArray)-1)
print modifiedPhrases
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acelives, I may contribute a bit.

Your code will return some of the permutations at first iteration, but empty lists for the next iterations. This is because your `phraseArray` is a list, and list is mutable, hence it is updated since the first iteration.

---

To avoid this, use `copy.deepcopy` :

```
wordChangeDict = {'for':'4',
                    'to': '2',
                    'late': 'l8'}

import copy


def phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index):
    phrase = copy.deepcopy(phrase)
    if index > len(phrase)-1:
        return resultStrings
    else:
        word = phrase[index]
        if word in wordChangeDict:
            phrase[index] = wordChangeDict[word]
            resultStrings.append(' '.join(phrase))
        return phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index+1)


testPhrase = "for now it is never to late"
phraseArray = testPhrase.split()
for idx, word in enumerate(phraseArray):
    modifiedPhrases = []
    modifiedPhrases = phrase2Slang(phraseArray, modifiedPhrases, idx)
    print modifiedPhrases
```

---

But notice that it is still does not give all the permutations you wanted.

---

To fix this, i can create a permutations of the Dict stored in a list, like this way :

```
wordChangeDict = {'for':'4',
                    'to': '2',
                    'late': 'l8'}
n = len(wordChangeDict)

import itertools
import copy

permDict_inList = []

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in itertools.combinations(wordChangeDict, i):
        permDict_inList.append({k : wordChangeDict[k] for k in j})
```

Then use that list as a filter, iterate through that list instead.

---

Result :

```
['for now it is never 2 l8', '4 now it is never to late', '4 now it is never to l8', '4 now it is never 2 l8', '4 now it is never 2 late', 'for now it is never 2 late', 'for now it is never to l8']
```

Full code :

```
wordChangeDict = {'for':'4',
                    'to': '2',
                    'late': 'l8'}
n = len(wordChangeDict)

import itertools
import copy

permDict_inList = []

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in itertools.combinations(wordChangeDict, i):
        permDict_inList.append({k : wordChangeDict[k] for k in j})


def phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index, FILTER):
    phrase = copy.deepcopy(phrase)
    if index > len(phrase)-1:
        return resultStrings
    else:
        word = phrase[index]
        if word in FILTER:
            phrase[index] = wordChangeDict[word]
            resultStrings.append(' '.join(phrase))
        return phrase2Slang(phrase, resultStrings, index+1, FILTER)


testPhrase = "for now it is never to late"
phraseArray = testPhrase.split()

modifiedPhrases = []
for PERM in permDict_inList:
    idx = 0
    modifiedPhrases = phrase2Slang(phraseArray, modifiedPhrases, idx, PERM)
    print list(set(modifiedPhrases))

result = list(set(modifiedPhrases))
```

Comment: Arief, thank you! I was originally working on a multi-recursive loop which didn't use the original for-loop, but I kept having issues, and it was because like you said - the list was mutable. I went back to that solution and was able to get everything completed inside by standard recursive loop. Your solution works as well, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quit doing this recursively: Python's itertools package has already implemented this for you.  You have a `product` to generate with a sequence of lists.  The choice points have two elements each; the fixed parts of the sentence have only one.  Your items are:

```
[
    ["for", "4"],
    ["now it is never"],
    ["to", "2"],
    ["late", "l8"]
]
```

Can you take it from there?

P.S. You misspelled "too".

Comment: The purpose of this function was to take unknown strings and map them against a much larger dictionary of possibilities. Specifically, I will be inputting lists of common English idioms and converting them with 'slang' to obtain all possible combinations. Using Python's itertools package, would the build out method be to take an input phrase, parse it out word by word, dynamically build a mapping (similar to what you built above), and then run it through itertools?